# Setting up navigation on a pioneer 2 platform using amcl and p2os

Tags: navigation, rviz, gmapping, amcl, p2os

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,
I'm trying to set up the navigationstack on a pioneer 2 robot. Up to a certain point, everything works fine. But when it comes to localizing itself on a previously recorded static map, it does not work like it's supposed to work.
I am using a hokuyo laser scanner and a teleoperation device, i was able to record a map, drive the robot around, visualize the map, etc.

This is my procedure to start the navigation:

- step 1 -  **roscore** (of course) then **rosrun p2os_driver p2os pose:=odom** (so move_base can use this)
- step 2 -  **rosrun map_server map_server /path_to_my_recorded_map map:=static_map**
- step 3 -  **roslaunch p2os_launch gmapping_tf_lrf_p2os_teleop_joy.launch** (launchfile provided by ros)
- step 4 -  **roslaunch p2os_launch navigation.launch**
- step 5 -  **rosrun rviz rviz**

In Rviz i was setting up everything described [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation/Tutorials/Using%20rviz%20with%20the%20Navigation%20Stack). 
Eventually i end up with rviz displaying everything just fine (map, footprint, etc.) After that i publish an initial goal, where the robot actually is on the recorded map. But here i encounter the problem: the footprint is not set in the particlecloud! The particlecloud moves as the robot moves and gets smaller as i move the robot, but he does actually understands that the robot is in the "middle of the cloud". Futhermore amcl announces that the sensor origin is out of map bounds - of course, because the sensor is not set in the 2d pose estimate.

Here is what my *local_costmap_params.yaml* looks like:

```
local_costmap:
global_frame: /odom
robot_base_frame: base_link
update_frequency: 5.0
publish_frequency: 2.0
static_map: false
rolling_window: false
width: 5.0
height: 5.0
resolution: 0.05
```

global_costmap_params.yaml

```
global_costmap:
global_frame: /map
robot_base_frame: base_link
update_frequency: 5.0
static_map: true
```

base_local_planner.yaml

```
TrajectoryPlannerROS:
max_vel_x: 1.2
min_vel_x: 0.2
max_rotational_vel: 0.8
min_in_place_rotational_vel: 0.3

#sim_time: 2.0
path_distance_bias: 0.6
goal_distance_bias: 0.6

acc_lim_th: 3.2
acc_lim_x: 2.5
acc_lim_y: 2.5

holonomic_robot: false
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12234/setting-up-navigation-on-a-pioneer-2-platform-using-amcl-and-p2os/) by [silentbutler](https://answers.ros.org/users/1497/silentbutler/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-12-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not sure how much of the problem is related to this, but I just noticed that for your local costmap, you have both `rolling window` and `static map` set to false. This would technically mean that you have no local costmap. In your configuration, you probably want to set `rolling window` to true.

**EDIT**: Based on your new information (which should be appended to the original question with an edit, rather than as an answer next time), all you need to do is modify navigation.launch in the p2os_launch package. Within the move_base node, you need to add a `<remap>`.

```
    <node pkg="move_base" type="move_base" respawn="false" name="move_base" output="screen">
        ...
        <remap from="map" to="static_map" />    
    </node>
```

What this does is tell move_base to look at the "/static_map" topic rather than the "/map" topic.

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2011-12-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1